# How do I simplify this equation using boolean logic?

Tags: boolean-algebra

[image]

I tried using reduntion, absortion and consensus but all of them were impossible to use.

Comment: You might find it easier to do visually using a Karnaugh map: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map - that may help visualise how to use the more formal rules of Boolean algebra. A K-map is suitable for minterm (which is what you have above).

Comment: are you sure it can be simplified further? I passed it through LogicFriday and it won't simply

Answer (score 1):

The only way to "simplify" this equation would be to introduce XOR and XNOR operations. By inspection you can determine that an odd number of variables must be true, which indicates that it uses XOR.

\$S_i = A_i \oplus B_i \oplus C_{i-1}\$

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simplify it further without introducing the \$\oplus\$ (XOR) operator.
The \$\oplus\$ operator is defined as:
$$
A \oplus B = \bar A \cdot B + A \cdot \bar B = ( A + B ) \cdot ( \bar A + \bar B )
$$

This allows us to rewrite the equation:
$$
S_i = \bar{A_l}\bar{B_l}C_{i-1} + \bar{A_l}{B_l}\bar{C_{i-1}}
+ {A_l}\bar{B_l}\overline{C_{i-1}} + {A_l}{B_l}{C_{i-1}}\\
= \bar{A_l}(\bar{B_l}C_{i-1} + {B_l}\bar{C_{i-1}})
+ {A_l}(\bar{B_l}\overline{C_{i-1}} + {B_l}{C_{i-1}})
$$
Using De Morgan's law to reformulate
$$
\bar{B_l}\overline{C_{i-1}} + {B_l}{C_{i-1}}
= \overline{B_l + C_{i-1}} + \overline{\bar{B_l} + \overline{C_{i-1}}}
= \overline{ (B_l + C_{i-1}) \cdot ( \bar{B_l} + \overline{C_{i-1}}) }
$$
We get:
$$
S_i = \bar{A_l}(\bar{B_l}C_{i-1} + {B_l}\bar{C_{i-1}})
+ {A_l}\left(\overline{ (B_l + C_{i-1}) \cdot ( \bar{B_l} + \overline{C_{i-1}}) }\right) 
$$
Using our new operation \$\oplus\$ this can be written:
$$
S_i = \bar{A_l}({B_l} \oplus C_{i-1})
+ {A_l}(\overline{ {B_l} \oplus C_{i-1} })\\
= A_l \oplus (B_l \oplus C_{i-1} )\\
= A_l \oplus B_l \oplus C_{i-1}
$$

Or we could have written a truth table:

```
   BC|0 0|0 1|1 0|1 1
 A   |   |   |   |   
-----+---+---+---+---
 0   | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 
-----+---+---+---+---
 1   | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1
```

Here we see that \$S_i\$ is true exactly if an odd number of the inputs \$A_l, B_l, C_{i-1}\$ are true. This is exactly how the \$\oplus\$ operator works.